# Why do I have to specify !important to a hover pseudo-class for it take effect?

Tags: css

I had to use the `!important` property for a hover style to take effect. The code below would not work without me including the `!important` property. Why is that?

**Non-working code**

```
#sbw a.content_copy:link {
    color: #F12B63;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sbw a.content_copy:visited {
    color: #F12B63;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sbw a.content_copy:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #F12B63;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

**Working code**

```
#sbw a.content_copy:link {
    color: #F12B63;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sbw a.content_copy:visited {
    color: #F12B63;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sbw a.content_copy:hover {
    color: #ffffff !important;
    background-color: #F12B63;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

Comment: post pastebin of entire css, must be a conflict somewhere. Also, which browser?

Comment: This should work, buddy. Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/WnY7P/
Looks like you have a conflicting css somewhere.

Comment: @Kayo/Aditya Saxena - I would most probably concur but seeing that I didn't write the original stylesheet and it exceeds almost a thousand lines, I am having a hard time nailing what is causing it to conflict.  What is the best way to find what it is conflicting with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules with `:visited` and `:link` may appear to be more specific.

You may do this :

```
#sbw a.content_copy:hover, #sbw a.content_copy:visited:hover, #sbw a.content_copy:link:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #F12B63;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What does that do exactly?

Comment: It makes the rule more specific. But I'm not sure it's needed in your case as I had no problem with your first CSS in Chrome or Firefox. If my answer isn't enough to clear your problem, I'd suggest you to build a complete online example demonstrating it, for example in http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Thanks. Would you only do that for the final pseudo class i.e. hover or is that for the entire declaration of all 3 pseudo-classes?

Comment: If you have no other rules, there is no reason for the two first to be overridden : they're exclusive and as long as the mouse isn't over them, the third rule can't be triggered. So don't change them.

Comment: I thought the order in which the pseudo-classes had appear were `link, visited, hover` & `active`?

Answer (score 1):

```
color: #ffffff !important;
```

this only ensures that on Hover color `#ffffff` will always be applied.
for Example :-

```
p { color: red !important; }
 p { color: blue; }
```

For the `paragraph` color will always be red, irrespective of second line CSS.

**Why to use `!important`**
Suppose you are writing css for your page in which you added a style  `p { color: red ;}`
on the first line but later on you again added  `p { color: blue;}` for same element, So 
your first style will be gone and always second style will applied by browser.
So if you add `!important` with your style it enforce browser to stick with that only.